# Udon Noodles break too easily

Tags: dough, noodles, japanese-cuisine, kneading

I tried making Udon noodles several times and even though I've gotten a rhythm to do them, I still can't figure out why they break so easy when I blanch them. I use

```
1tsp lye water
8 ounces (1 cup) warm water
2 1/2 cups unbleached bread flour
1 1/4 cups unbleached all-purpose flour
```

I blanch them for about 7 minutes and roll it until 1/16 of a inch thick.

When eating them with chopsticks they don't even make it that far because they break. It might be the weight on them but they break.

How can I improve my udon noodles so that they don't break?

Comment: I don't know if this is related. I remember when we made fish-balls without adding tapioca flour, they crumbled easily.

Comment: Shouldn't it be all bread flour? The protein content is higher in bread flour and helps to form the gluten threads that give the noodles their texture. Also, are you sure you are kneading them enough to get the gluten going?

Comment: I might be kneading too long perhaps. I form the dough ball let it rest for about 1hour, then need it for about 45 minutes or until I feel like its started to be more elastic, form another ball let it rest until the next day approx 16hr in a 72 degree room covered with a plastic bag, Then I flattened it out/Knead it again for about 10 minutes let it rest for 1 hour and start rolling it. However when I roll it the dough is somewhat elastic but if I try to pull it with my hands it will break easily like if I was breaking apart a piece of plastiline or playdoh.

Comment: I figured it out. It wasnt the dough really. It was the way I was cutting the noodles and How long i wastaing. they will dry out if you take too long and brake easily. if they start breaking when you are cutting them they will most likely brake after you blanch them. I also add some tapioca flour to my dough and let it rest for 2 days. this made the dough more elastic and easier to roll.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that kneading pasta too long has the same effect. Try reducing the kneading time.

Comment: I knead this batch less and so far looks rell good